# How to find biggest number using Math object with Prompt and FOR loop or do/while loop?

Tags: javascript

My goal was to find the biggest number using the Math object in the console. However, How could I use the FOR loop to PROMPT the number 1, number 2 so that I don't have to write the whole object? I just wanted to return the value each time I use for loop but could not think that way so later I had to write an object.

```
var num = {

x: parseInt(prompt("Enter your number1")),
Y: parseInt(prompt("Enter your number2")),
W: parseInt(prompt("Enter your number1")),
Z: parseInt(prompt("Enter your number1")),

}

console.log(Math.max(num.x, num.Y,num.Z,num.W));
```

Comment: Loops don't return anything, only functions can use `return`.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over the Object's keys

```js
var num = {
  x: 0,
  Y: 0,
  W: 0,
  Z: 0,
}

Object.keys(num).forEach(key => num[key] = +prompt(`Enter your ${key}`));

// Object.keys(num).forEach(function(key) { 
//   num[key] = +prompt('Enter your ' + key);
// });

console.log(num);
```

for loop and an array

```js
var nums = [];

for (var i=0; i<4; i++) {
  nums.push(+prompt('Enter your ' + i));
}

console.log(nums);
console.log(Math.max(...nums));
```

Comment: Not wrong, but this guy seems like a coding beginner and using lambdas to loop over keysets might be a bit advanced.

Comment: Thanks so much. Yes, I am a complete beginner. I wanted to use the FOR loop to trigger the PROMPT multiple times but struggled to get each LOOP value in the consol to compare the numbers in the MATH object. 

For example:
for (var i=0; I<3; i++)

{

}

I wanted to get all the values it returns for i.

Comment: So push them to an array. The forEach is like a for loop. It was just looping over all the keys of the object.

Comment: FANTASTIC!! With my level, this was the one I was looking for. Thanks @epascarello
The best.

Comment: @epascarello Your `.keys().forEach()` solution is incomplete. It doesn't show how to get the max of the numbers after you set them to the object keys. `Math.max(...Object.values(num))`

Comment: @mhodges it is no different than what OP did in theirs.... I figured they were using those hardcoded values.

Comment: Meh, it doesn't play nicely with N number of object keys, like your `for(...)` solution does. Figured you may as well put a complete answer since the OP is trying to learn